# Django rest api, Shazamio

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, shazam

```
I am using shazamio library with django rest api. An unexpected error occurred. Can you help?
```

[image]
[image]

The response should be returned in json format but I am getting an error.

By: Yandex translate

Comment: try return Response(out)  , also check type of 'out' , check whether its dict

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpyO.png The solution